# How to speed up .olm importing process into outlook 2019 for MAC which is dead slow

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2016, microsoft-outlook-2019

I was to reset my macbook-2018 (Mac-OS Mojave 16GB+500GB-SSD. So I exported "on my computer folder as .olm file which is about 100+ GB, so that later on I can access  my downloaded emails".

Now, its taking about one week to import the .olm file into outlook 2019 for mac.

After googling I only found some paid software solutions.

is there any effective solution for the said issue?

Comment: Why did you think your Mac even needed "resetting"? Why did you not, even after that, just migrate from Time Machine? The effective solution would be to have not done that in the first place. Macs don't need 'resetting' [neither does Windows, though there are stronger arguments for it on Windows, there are none for Mac].

Comment: @Tetsujin Hoping for the best

Comment: Yeah… it doesn't really work like that. The misinformation is a self-fulfilling prophesy, spread by Win users with no factual basis except "My machine was slow, so I reinstalled the OS & it got faster"… which it would had they filled it with useless junk, PUPs & other torr… ermm suspicious processes that were hogging the machine. It doesn't explain that it was their own malpractice that weighed it down in the first place. Anything you put on a machine, you can easily take off again.

Answer (score 0):

I only found the Official KB mentioned commonly used method. Since the profile file is 100+ GB, it will cost much time to import. I suggest you split the data file into 10 sub files, then import them one by one.

[Import email messages, contacts, and other items into Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-email-messages-contacts-and-other-items-into-outlook-for-mac-6cc48404-a65c-4b8c-a12a-95a905249414)